# Execute Insert Query without inserting any rows?

Tags: mysql, oracle

How to execute an insert query without inserting any rows in the database.

I tried this, but this isn't working.

```
insert
into   table_name
values ()
;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using Oracle or MySQL? What is the meaning of such an insert? Do you want to test a statement level trigger or something? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicolasKrasnov: I think the confusion is in the fact it is now Oracle MySQL

Comment: @PatrickHofman Still two different engines.

Comment: @Nicholas my mentor asked me this question.

Comment: @VikasHardia So tell your mentor that you don't know. How else will the mentor be able to mentor you?

Comment: @DavidAldridge: sure but have got some different prospective here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an `INSERT` statement without inserting any rows then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>
SELECT ... WHERE <any condition which will never be true>
```

**MySQL 5.6.6 m9 Schema Setup** - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/740d4/2):

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  A INT PRIMARY KEY,
  B INT DEFAULT 42,
  C CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Test'
);

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 1 = 0;
```

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup** - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53d5c/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  A NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  B NUMBER DEFAULT 42,
  C CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Test'
);

INSERT INTO Test
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server it is

```
insert into table_name default values
```

From MySQL documentation:

If both the column list and the VALUES list are empty, INSERT creates a row with each column set to its default value:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES();
```

Comment: the above mention queries are inserting one row in table with null values of all column :(

Comment: You can also use DEFAULT(col_name) as a more general form that can be used in expressions to produce a given column's default value.

Comment: yeah i can use that but at the end it will insert a row in the table i do not want to insert any row in table.

Comment: @VikasHardia: okay, that wasn't clear in your question.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience